# Yii2 Insert multiple records of a same table

Tags: php, forms, yii2, active-form

I Have my model with 2 fields Product.php:

```
[['ID_PRODUCT'], 'integer'],
[['NAME_PRODUCT'], 'string'],
```

my Controller ProductController.php:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID_PRODUCT]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And i want insert many times the same table with ActiveForm:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_PRODUCT')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'NAME_PRODUCT')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ID_PRODUCT')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'NAME_PRODUCT')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
     </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

But when i save the information the fields are overwritten and only the last record is inserted

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are trying to do is collect, validate and save tabular data. The reason it doesn't work is that in the form, Yii generates a name tag based on the field name and model, e.g. `name="[Product]["ID_PRODUCT"]`. When the form is sent to the server, the first fields get overwritten by the last ones, as they have the same name. The correct way to collect tabular input in a form is to add brackets at the end of the name, like this; `name="[1][Product]["ID_PRODUCT"]`.Using this method, Yii gives ways of loading and validating multiple models.

Modify your controller code to use multiple models;

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate(){

        //Find out how many products have been submitted by the form
        $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('Product', []));

        //Send at least one model to the form
        $products = [new Product()];

        //Create an array of the products submitted
        for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $products[] = new Product();
        }

        //Load and validate the multiple models
        if (Model::loadMultiple($products, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($products)) {

            foreach ($products as $product) {

                //Try to save the models. Validation is not needed as it's already been done.
                $product->save(false);

            }
            return $this->redirect('view');
        }

    return $this->render('create', ['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

Now you have all the data you need to populate the form, including any error messages generated for individual instances of you `product` model. The view file for the form needs to be altered like this, to use the multiple models;

```
foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
    echo $form->field($product, "[$index]ID_PRODUCT")->label($product->ID_PRODUCT);
    echo $form->field($product, "[$index]NAME_PRODUCT")->label($product->NAME_PRODUCT);
}
```

All of this is covered in the [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html)